# WinAPI: tabcontrol, images and line breaks

Tags: c, winapi

I'm using a child window with tabs to show the results of my program. There are no buttons or other controls needed on the tabs, just some text and images. However, all I could achieve so far was to place some text without line breaks on the tab.

This is what I use to create my output window:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ChildProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    TCITEMW tie;
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;

    switch(msg) {

        case WM_CREATE:

          icex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
          icex.dwICC = ICC_TAB_CLASSES;
          InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);

          // Create tab control
          hTab = CreateWindowW(WC_TABCONTROLW, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                0, 0, X_FENSTER-15, Y_FENSTER-120, hWnd,(HMENU) ID_TABCTRL, NULL, NULL);

        // Create 8 tabs
        int i;
            tie.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
            for (i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                // Set labels for tab 
                switch(i){
                    case 0: tie.pszText = L"Übersicht";
                            break;
                    case 1: tie.pszText = L"Einzel";
                            break;
                    case 2: tie.pszText = L"Topol. 1";
                            break;
                    case 3: tie.pszText = L"Topol. 2";
                            break;
                    case 4: tie.pszText = L"Topol. 3";
                            break;
                    case 5: tie.pszText = L"Topol. 4";
                            break;
                    case 6: tie.pszText = L"Topol. 5";
                            break;
                    case 7: tie.pszText = L"Topol. 6";
                            break;
                }

                // Create tab          
                SendMessageW(hTab, TCM_INSERTITEMW, (LRESULT)i, (LPARAM) (LPTCITEM) &tie);

            // Receive string to write on tab
                wchar_t puffer[ERGSTRING];
                ausgabe(i - 1, puffer);  // writes string to puffer

            // Write string on tab
                kartei[i] = CreateWindowExW(0, L"STATIC", puffer, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_CENTER | SS_CENTERIMAGE ,  // control style
                            175,         // x position
                            75,         // y position
                            200,        // control width
                            60,         // control height
                            hTab,       // parent control
                            (HMENU)i,       // menu/ID info
                            hInst,     // instance handler
                            NULL        // no extra creation data
                );
                ShowWindow(kartei[i], SW_HIDE);
            }

                            ShowWindow(kartei[0], SW_SHOW);  // First tab to the foreground


            // Create Button (BTN_CLOSE)
            CreateWindowW(WC_BUTTONW, L"Schließen", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
                80, Y_FENSTER - 90, 80, 30, hWnd, (HMENU) BTN_CLOSE, NULL, NULL);
            break;
```

The result looks like this:

[Screenshot of my output window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZcnc.png)

However, I'd like to display multiple lines of text and add a picture. I already tried to load a bitmap using this:

```
HANDLE bmp7 = LoadImageA(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE (8002), 0, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
            if (bmp7 == NULL) MessageBox(NULL, "Bitmap not loaded.", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
```

This returns a handle to the bitmap I'd like to show. The Error message is not triggered, but I do not know how to place this image on my tab. What can I do?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what you are trying to accomplish. Are you looking to place multi-line titles on tabs along with images? Also, from your screenshot it appears that you are using the old common controls. You can use the new common controls by [enabling visual styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/cookbook-overview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problems.

- Line breaks: Those were disabled, since I used the wrong window style. I now use  SS_LEFT instead of SS_CENTER and SS_CENTERIMAGE.
- Images: I had to create separate HWNDs for the images. Now I use the following code.

  ```
  HANDLE topoBitmap = LoadImageA(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE (8000+i), 0, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
  if (topoBitmap != NULL){
      kartei[i+8] = CreateWindowExW(0, L"STATIC", puffer, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT | SS_BITMAP,
                      20, 75, 100, 100, hTab, (HMENU)i, hInst, NULL);
      SendMessage(kartei[i+8], STM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM) IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM) topoBitmap);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you can convert the images to icons that would be the easy way to deal with this, Most of the standard controls (and the static control in particular) can only deal with icons and not regular bitmaps.

If that is not an option your next best choice would likely be to create another window class whose instances would act as the tab control client area. That class would then be responsible for drawing the bitmap and text you are interested in showing.

Comment: A static control can display regular bitmaps just fine (see [STM_SETIMAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/stm-setimage)).

Comment: Bitmaps work perfectly. I now use a STM_SETIMAGE message. Thank you for pointing this out, IInspectable.